# Which field should I edit to make the checkbox marked by default?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a php form that I want to change the state of a checkbox so it's filled by default, but there are two fields that may be the right way:

```
'request_vendor_access' => array(
                'label'    => __( 'Request access to become an Artist', 'ignitewoo_vendor_stores' ),
                'type'        => 'checkbox',
                'required' => false,
                'class'    => array( 'form-row-full vendor_stores_request_access' ),
                'clear'    => true,
                'default'    => 'go',
            ),
```

I would have guessed that it would be 'default', but it's set to the string 'go' so perhaps I should set `clear` to `false`.

What's the correct way to make the checkbox marked by default? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Of course you have tried `TRUE` and `'checked'` already, have you?

Comment: `checked` works in the html but I need to change it in the php file instead. Where would you recommend I add `TRUE`?

Comment: `'default' => TRUE`. In Drupal it's `'default_value' => TRUE`. And remove `'clear' => TRUE'`.

Comment: Yes it is definitively `'default' => true` or `'default' => '1'`

Comment: Don't edit plugin files. You'll lose your changes if/when it's updated. Check the plugin docs or contact its author to find out the supported way to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely must is `'default' => TRUE`.

```
'request_vendor_access' => [
  'label'    => __('Request access to become an Artist', 'ignitewoo_vendor_stores'),
  'type'     => 'checkbox',
  'required' => FALSE,
  'class'    => ['form-row-full vendor_stores_request_access'],
  'clear'    => TRUE,
  'default'  => TRUE,
]
```

If not, also try `'default_value'  => TRUE,` or try it without `'clear'`.

Depending on what you want to achieve you might also want to get the default value dynamically. So that it restores the user's choice. Maybe [`get_option($option, $default)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) is the right choice here (if that's an Options API form).

```
'request_vendor_access' => [
  'label'    => __('Request access to become an Artist', 'ignitewoo_vendor_stores'),
  'type'     => 'checkbox',
  'required' => FALSE,
  'class'    => ['form-row-full vendor_stores_request_access'],
  'clear'    => TRUE,
  'default'  => get_option('request_vendor_access', TRUE),
]
```

or

```
'request_vendor_access' => [
  'label'    => __('Request access to become an Artist', 'ignitewoo_vendor_stores'),
  'type'     => 'checkbox',
  'required' => FALSE,
  'class'    => ['form-row-full vendor_stores_request_access'],
  'clear'    => TRUE,
  'default'  => isset(get_option('my_option')['request_vendor_access'] ? get_option('my_option')['request_vendor_access'] : TRUE,
]
```